# The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html') for firebase messaging service integration in vue js

Tags: vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

Thank you in advance,
                    I want to enable the push notification service of a firebase in my Vue js App. But while adding the below code, I am getting an error.

## main.js (the file is on root)

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
          if (permission === 'granted') {
              messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                    updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
                    alert('Token Available')
                } else {
                    updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
                    setTokenSentToServer(false);
                    alert('Token Not Available')
                }
              }).catch((err) => {

              })
          } else {

          }
        });
```

## firebase-messaging-sw.js (the file is on root)

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
   'messagingSenderId': '<message-sending id>'
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/itwonders-web-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

But I am getting below error

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')
```

Comment: I'm curious if you figured this out, I'm dealing with this right now and it is driving me insane. I cannot figure out how to get the registerServiceWorker.js that Vue provides and firebase-messaging-sw.js to work together.

Comment: @Onyoursix, try the below solution

Answer (score 0):

@Onyoursix, Try to place firebase-messaging-sw.js into the public folder like {project_root}\public\firebase-messaging-sw.js and try with the below code and remove everything relevant to firebase push notifications code

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
    apiKey: "{YOUR_APIKEY}",
    authDomain: "{YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN}",
    databaseURL: "{YOUR_DATABASE_UR}",
    projectId: "{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}",
    storageBucket: "{YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET}",
    messagingSenderId: "{YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}",
    appId: "{YOUR_APP_ID}"
      }
firebase.initializeApp(config)
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: I found what my issue is, not sure how to fix it yet though - still working through it. Basically, when I build it's not building my service-worker.js file in my /dist folder. It puts the registerServiceWorker.js file that vue generates in there. This sounds like it may not be a common issue, but if you have any ideas, would love to hear them. I'm using InjectManifest for my workboxPluginMode

Comment: Have you tried putting firebase-messaging-sw.js in the public folder?

Comment: I was able to fix this. I had firebase-messaging-sw.js in the public folder but it would just never register both my service worker files.

I moved the firebase-messaging-sw.js to the /src folder and changed this in Vue.config.js I changed

workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
    }

That seemed to do it. I just use that file as my main service worker now.

Comment: @Onyoursix, okay fine but putting firebase-messaging-sw.js in the public folder resolved issue for me